# promise js как вытащить данные

Tags: javascript

получаю такой промис, как мне вытащить из него данные и занести в переменную?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код:

```js
async function fetchDate(key, zone) {
  const result = await fetch(`http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?${key}&format=json&by=zone&zone=${zone}`);

  return result;
}

let result = fetchDate(key, newYorkZone);
let newYorktime = result.then(json => json.json());
console.log(newYorktime)
```

Comment: Может помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554337/321883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно написать одельную функцию по выполнению каких либо задач, например, для вывода в консоль значения время Нью Йорка:

```js
const setTimeNewYork = (time) => {
    console.log(time)
    //либо другие операции
}

result.then(response => {
    data = response.json()
    data.then((value) => {
        setTimeNewYork(value[key])
        console.log(value[key])//value представлено как Object
        console.log(Object.keys(value))//просмотр всех ключей в виде массива
        console.log(Object.values(value))//просмотр всех значений в виде массива
    })
});
```